# Git Credential Login Keeps Pop-upping after installing visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After installing visual studio 2017, there is always a pop-up dialog for Git Credential Login. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Install the Git Credential Manager**

Download and run the latest Git for [Windows installer](https://git-scm.com/download/win), which includes the Git Credential Manager for Windows. Make sure to leave the Git Credntial Manager installation option enabled when prompted.

Git Credential Managers simplify authentication with your Team Services/TFS Git repos. Credential Managers let you use the same credentials that you use for the Team Services/TFS web interface and support multi-factor authentication through Microsoft Account (MSA) or Azure Active Directory (AAD). In addition to supporting multi-factor authentication with Team Services, the credential managers also provide support two-factor authentication with GitHub repositories.

refer [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers)