# How in SourceTree to get rid of a window "Git credential manager for Windows"?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

After adding the repository, a window with the heading "git credential manager for windows" constantly pops up.
Whatever I do (enter different logins and passwords, cancel), it then appears again. And in more than two copies.
How to get rid of it?

I have registered the following settings in the `.hgrc` file, but this does not help.

```
[auth]
repo.prefix = http://to.my.repo
repo.username = <login>
repo.password = <pass>
repo.schemes = http
```

[image: git credential manager for windows]

I placed the question on the site atlassian.com. I hope for a solution) Here is the link.
[How-in-SourceTree-to-get-rid-of-a-window-Git-credential-manager](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/How-in-SourceTree-to-get-rid-of-a-window-Git-credential-manager/qaq-p/631170#M16498) on community.atlassian.com

I asked a question, but could not get an answer. I did everything that I was advised, but nothing works. Why does the "Git credential manager for Windows" window access an https server?

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-tries-to-enter-quot-https-quot-although-the-settings/qaq-p/634852#M16629

Comment: Maybe because the window mentions "git" and you are adding credentials to a mercurial configuration file ?

Comment: @marco.m That's just the point, that git I do not use!

Comment: Wrong tag `atlassian-sourcetree`, I believe this is about `visual-studio`, linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694161/git-credential-login-keeps-pop-upping-after-installing-visual-studio-2017

Comment: I asked a question, but could not get an answer. I did everything that I was advised, but nothing works. Why does the "Git credential manager for Windows" window access an https server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by the developers of the program. Description of what you need to do can be viewed on the page https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-tries-to-enter-quot-https-quot-although-the-settings/qaq-p/634852#U637810

Answer (score 0):

[The approach in this blogpost by Ben Gillbanks worked for me.](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/11/updating-sourcetree-git-login-credentials/)

In short:

- Open SourceTree and navigate to the repository you want to update the password of
- Click the ‘Terminal’ button to jump to the location of the repo on the command line
- Enter ‘Git Pull’ and hit return to update the repository
- When requested enter your password
- Done

In addition to this approach I first deleted the saved password from Tools>Options>Authentication but I don't know if this made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

1.Goto tools -> options

2.Uncheck "Check default remotes for updates evey [10] minutes"

3.Restart SourceTree!